# Font-size responsivo conforme o tamanho da tela

Tags: css, css-font-size

Como faço para que o meu texto aumente ou diminua juntamente com a dimensão da tela? Li um pouco sobre `rem`, mas não entendi muito bem.
Na verdade nem sei se isso se aplica ao caso.

Comment: Se é aumentar automaticamente, voce está procurando `CSS media queries`. Se for conforme o nível de zoom (caso comum aonde `rem` e `em` se aplicam) olhe minha segunda opção. Ela é complicada mas é excelente para layouts e textos flexíveis sem quebrar o layout.

Comment: Veja se o exemplo deste link atende https://journey.dev.br/article/a0300400001

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Automaticamente com tamanho de tela

Acesse essa documentação do [MDN sobre CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries). Como não detalhou exatamente os pontos de corte, fica complicado dar um exemplo prático e genérico demais. Porém o link acima explica muito bem como fazer isso.

### Para permitir que aumente com zoom do scroll (acessibilidade)

Em poucas palavras, um modo de fazer isso é definir um tamanho base do `body` apenas uma vez em `px` (por exemplo, `16px`), e a partir daí, toda e qualquer alteração de fonte ou então de tamanho de tela, até mesmo as larguras e alturas de elementos, deveriam ser definidas em `em`.

Isso também é uma questão de acessibilidade. Usar fontes fixas, em especial em navegadores mais antigos, impedia que a pessoa usasse o aumentar natural do navegador.

**O bom de definir em `em` ou outra unidade que seja relativa e não fixa, é que ao aumentar o zoom da página ela reage como se o tamanho da tela ficasse com largura menor pelo ponto de vista responsívo**. Uma pessoa em um computador com uma tela Full HD que aumentar o zoom muito irá ver o site como se estivesse acessando de um celular, o que é bem interessante se comparado a simplesmente só aumentar a fonte e os blocos de caixas com tamanho fixo não aumentarem e ficar uma bagunça.

Reparem que alguns navegadores modernos podem até permitir um efeito parecido ao aumentar o zoom mesmo que as unidades usadas não sejam em `em` ou outra unidade relativa, mas em algumas versões mais antigas isso não funciona.

Comment: Opa, legal sua resposta, mas já ia comentar que nos navegadores modernos já funciona o zoom mesmo usando pixels pras unidades. Entretanto, fica muito mais fácil ajustar as fontes via media queries utlizando REM e colocando uma base pro elemento html.

Answer (score 6):

Tenho duas opções.

1) Você pode usar um plugin para fazer isso, aqui tem um:

**[FLOW TYPE](http://simplefocus.com/flowtype/)**

2) Você pode fazer isso com media queries, onde você consegue definir em qual largura vai haver modificação, por exemplo:

```
/* Smaller than standard 960 (devices and browsers) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 959px) {
    p{
        font-size: 10px;
    }
}

/* Tablet Portrait size to standard 960 (devices and browsers) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 959px) {
    p{
        font-size: 12px;
    }
}

/* All Mobile Sizes (devices and browser) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    p{
        font-size: 14px;
    }
}

/* Mobile Landscape Size to Tablet Portrait (devices and browsers) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {
    p{
        font-size: 9px;
    }
}

/* Mobile Portrait Size to Mobile Landscape Size (devices and browsers) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
    p{
        font-size: 7px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Basta utilizar CSS que este já resolve desta maneira:

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 1550px)
{ css para este tamanho }

@media only screen and (min-width : 1400px) and (max-width : 1549px)
{ css para este tamanho}
```

Comment: Só no [Window Resizer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/window-resizer/kkelicaakdanhinjdeammmilcgefonfh) temos 10 dimensões diferentes para diferentes dispositivos. Torna-se custoso fazer diferentes estilos para essa variedade de dimensões. A ideia é fazer uma página adaptativa até certo ponto, no qual fique ruim de visualizar.

Comment: escolha as telas que quer atender, pois com media queries é o jeito mais concreto que conheço, independente de navegador

Answer (score -3):

Utilize font-size: 62.5% no .body depois basta usar o seguinte, para uma fonte de 16px, use 1.6em, para 24px, 2.4em, etc...

Comment: Isto não fornece uma resposta à pergunta o autor pediu uma explicação dos casos de uso das unidades CSS. Você fez uma mera citação que ficaria melhor como um comentário abaixo da publicação dele.

Answer (score -3):

Você pode usar a função `clamp()` do css.

```
p {
  font-size: clamp(1em, 1em + 1vw, 1.5em);
}
```

Na prática, o que está acontecendo é: o tamanho da fonte especificado é 1em + 1vw, mas ele nunca será menor que 1em, nem maior que 1.5em.

Aqui, você encontra um ótimo tutorial sobre o assunto: https://desenvolvimentoparaweb.com/css/textos-responsivos-com-css-clamp/

Comment: Prefira o link da [documentação oficial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clamp()) a tutoriais. Também explique que usar `clamp()` para tamanhos de fonte, permite definir um tamanho de fonte que varia com o tamanho da janela de visualização. E adicione um [MCVE] mostrando com funciona o seu argumento na prática. Faça o nosso [tour].

Comment: Olá Alan. É uma boa resposta e complementando o que o o @AugustoVasques, recomendo [edit] a resposta e melhorar ela dando um foco mais técnico, de preferência seguindo a documentação: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clamp() (já citada), https://www.w3.org/TR/css-values-4/#math e aproveitar para mencionar os navegadores com suporte e limitações existentes, um bom lugar para pesquisar: https://caniuse.com/?search=clamp()