# Fonte Responsiva conforme ajuste do tamanho da tela

Tags: css, css3, layout-responsivo

Tenho um site responsivo só que a letra mesmo colocando em %, Rem ou EM não fica ajustando.

Então será que é possível fazer a fonte alterar por exemplo uma janela com o comprimento em **1000px** e **fonte-size** em **1.8em (18px)**, subindo o comprimento da janela para **2000px** então o **fonte-size** sobe para o equivalente algo como **36px**?

Quero que a fonte ajuste seu valor conforme muda as dimensões da janela ou grid.

Comment: Um texto bastante interessante para complementar os conceitos: http://blog.popupdesign.com.br/design-responsivo-grids-e-texto/

Comment: Justamente nesse site encontramos um exemplo, já tentei mais não fica igual o texto no menu do popupdesign; no popup quando altura o browser altura a fonte, observe isso atentamente no maximizar e no minimizar. @Delfino

Comment: possível duplicata de [Font-size para páginas responsivas](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5271/font-size-para-p%c3%a1ginas-responsivas)

Comment: No caso eu tenho que Definir um fonte-size para cada resolução?
`@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {    
       body { font-size: 1.8rem; }    
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 2000px) {    
       body { font-size: 3.6rem; }
}
` pude verificar isso no popupdesigner @Delfino @Fabio Mingorance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {    
       body { font-size: 18px; }    
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 2000px) {    
       body { font-size: 36px; }
}
```

Apenas um detalhe, a medida **em** para fontes não tem relação proporcional direta em **px** e sim com o zoom de cada navegador. Geralmente 1em equivale a 16px em boa parte dos monitores.

Comment: Amigo até ai ja sei o problema é que quando tenho `@media only screen and (min-width: 700px)and (max-width: 1000px)` não muda a fonta ou seja ela não reajusta, ela continua com um mesmo valor em `px mesmo colocando em EM % ou REM` @Fabio Mingorance

Answer (score 4):

Que tal esse [exemplo de código](http://jsfiddle.net/xfrxk3y3/)? Eu achei esse [blog post](http://desenvolvimentoparaweb.com/css/unidades-css-rem-vh-vw-vmin-vmax-ex-ch/) em português, mas o resumo da ópera é que `1vw` é 1% da largura da tela, `1vh` é 1% da altura da tela, e `vmin` e `vmax` são 1% da menor e maior dimensão, respectivamente. As duas primeiras unidades de medida funcionam em qualquer IE 9+.

(você pode arrastar as divisórias do grid no JSFiddle pra ver o efeito)

- [especificação CSS 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths) (inglês)
- [referência MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths) (inglês)